# How to solve this integral involving exponential and exponential of exponential?

Tags: integration, probability-theory, normal-distribution, moment-generating-functions

I would like to find the moment generating function of 
$$
e^{-a-bX^2},
$$
where X is $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$.

This is equivalent to compute the following integral :
$$
I = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{te^{-a-bx^2}}e^{\frac{-(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}dx.
$$

Any hint on how to integrate this? I guess it should involve substitution, but I don't see what could be efficient here.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: HINT:Try numerics.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk thanks, but I need to end up with an analytical function

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk I misread it. Sorry!

Comment: Finding the actual distribution may be easier this time, your random variable is a function of a chi-squared r.v. $X^2$ but seriously are you sure about your r.v. because if it is only $-a-bX^2$ completing the exponent to square is the way to go. By the way you need another radical like $t$ in your MGF.

Comment: @keoxkeox Yes you are right, it's fixed now. And I computed the PDF of my total r.v. (including the exponent), but it is really ugly and I don't know neither how to integrate it, I think this way should be easier. As far as I know, the PDF of $-a-bX^2$ is not any specific distribution, right?

Answer (score 0):

Notice that by symmetry of the Gaussian, the even order moments vanish.

Then by parts, borrowing an $x$ from $x^{2n}$,

$$M_{2n}=\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^{2n}e^{-x^2/2}dx=-\left.x^{2n-1}e^{-x^2/2}\right|_{-\infty}^\infty+(2n-1)\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^{2n-2}e^{-x^2/2}dx=(2n-1)M_{2n-2}$$ and by induction

$$M_{2n}=(2n-1)!!M_0.$$

Comment: I'm lost here. What happened to the exponential of exponential?

Comment: @Ségo: this is not the moment generating function, these are the moments proper, from which you can draw the MGF.